# Shoot function in Javascript broken and image not showing up

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

I have this code.

```js
var scene;

function start() {
  scene = $('a-scene')[0];
  console.log("The scene is ready", scene);
}


AFRAME.registerComponent("start-game", {
  init: start
});

function fire(bullet, aim) {
  var newBullet = $(bullet).clone();
  newBullet.attr('visible', 'true');

  var bulletPos = $(bullet).attr('position');
  var target = aim.x + ' ' + bulletPos.y + ' ' + aim.z;

  newBullet.attr('animation', 'property:position; to:' + target + '; dur:5000');
  $(scene).append(newBullet);
}

function shoot() {
  var bullet = this.data;
  $(this.el).on('click', function(evt) {
    var aim = evt.detail.intersection.point;
    fire(bullet, aim);
  });
}

AFRAME.registerComponent("shoot", {
  schema: {
    type: "selector"
  },
  init: shoot
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Plants vs Zombies</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component@1.1.0/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene start-game>
    <a-sky color='skyblue'>
    </a-sky>
    <a-obj-model src="TennisCourt.obj" mtl="TennisCourt.mtl" position="1 2 -6">
    </a-obj-model>


    <a-obj-model class='.tennisBall' src="Tennis_Ball.obj" mtl="Tennis_Ball.mtl" scale="0.4 0.4 0.4" position="8 4 -6" animation="property:position; from:8 4 -6; to:-8 4 -6; dur:1500; loop:true;"></a-obj-model>
    <a-camera position="9 4.2 -6">
      <a-cursor shoot=".tennisBall"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```

[Files I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3YGh.png)

How do I fix it because the tennis ball shows up as black without the image file on it, and also the shoot function isn't working. This is an image. I am really not sure what happened to it and anyone who can tell me what went wrong would be a big help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biXyE.png)

Comment: I made a snippet it gives console errors, can you fix them?

Comment: It is missing the .mtl